# Values with commas are changed after converting .xlsx to .csv

Tags: r, excel, csv, merge, number-formatting

I have ~3200 `.xlsx` files I want to merge into one file. These files consist of several columns which contain values with commas. After converting the files to `.csv`, most of the commas are changed to `"."` and thus the values are displayed correctly. In other colums, the commas are omitted which leads to wrong values in the columns. However, this does not happen, if the value can be rounded to `.5` or `.0`.

Example:

```
time_elapsed  x_pred_normalised
0              0,5153
0              0,5153
10,457283      0,7824
17,458956      0,8451
82,000000      0,4511
```

This is how it looks in the `.xlsx`-file. After converting it to `.csv` the same part in the file looks like this:

```
time_elapsed  x_pred_normalised
0              0.5153
0              0.5153
10457283       0.7824
17458956       0.8451
82             0.4511
```

To convert the files from `.xlsx` to `.csv` I used `r` and this code:

```
library(readxl)

# increase max.print
options(max.print=2000)

# Create a vector of Excel files to read
files.to.read = list.files(pattern="xlsx")

# Read each file and write it to csv
lapply(files.to.read, function(f) {
  df = read_excel(f, sheet=1)
  write.csv(df, gsub("xlsx", "csv", f), row.names=FALSE)
})
```

I am new to `r` (and anything related to programming and stuff) and I don't know how to fix this. I tried converting the files with `windows terminal` and also tried [Batch convert Excel files of a folder to CSV files with VBA](https://www.extendoffice.com/documents/excel/5537-excel-batch-convert-to-csv.html). Each of these options produces the same problem, but in different places of the file.
I.e. the last option omitted the comma, if the values in `x_pred_normalised` were `>1`.

If there's anything I can do, please help me. This is part of the preprocessing process of my eye-tracking data, which I need for my M.A.-thesis.

Comment: What format are the cells in the XLSX? If it's "Number", you should be able to change the display of the decimal. this does not change the actual value, just the way it is displayed.

Comment: Do the original xlsx documents have commas as the decimal indicator?

Comment: Since `write.csv` defaults to `dec="."` (dot), my guess is that `read_excel` sees that data as strings (`character`), not as numbers. You an add `df[] <- lapply(df, type.convert, dec=",", as.is=TRUE)` after your call to `read_excel`, and then write to the CSV.

Comment: Ultimately if you have a process creating those xlsx files, it's best to fix the process. If you have humans producing them, then I suggest you add a step into their processing that includes either (a) verifying that the columns are formatted as `Number` (excel cell-type), or (b) ask if they can change their locale/formatting convention when saving the documents. (Part of me wonders if Excel stores it as a number and only adds commas or points for printing, in which case only (a) would be relevant.)